# Elasticsearch: searching a field containing an array of objects, ignoring some/ranking some differently

Tags: elasticsearch

I have objects of the following structure:

```
{ "contents" : [ { "type": "A", "content": "something"},
                 { "type": "B", "content": "else"} ]}
```

(This is just an example, A or B could be present or not, there might also be C etc.).

I want to search within the contents of the array, but only those of type "A". At other times, i'd like to rank results higher if the text is contained in an "A".

Is this possible doing elastic search? Several musts seem to not help since I need to make sure A has the content, not that A or B has the content and that A is present.

I prefer not to change the structure of the objects that are indexed.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's add mapping for your structure first:

```
POST test_index/test_type/_mapping
{
   "test_type": {
      "properties": {
         "contents": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
               "type": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "content": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Now let's add some sample docs:

```
POST test_index/test_type/1
{
  "contents": [
    {
      "type": "A",
      "content": "one two three"
    },
    {
      "type": "B",
      "content": "four five six"
    }
  ]
}

POST test_index/test_type/2
{
  "contents": [
    {
      "type": "A",
      "content": "one two three four"
    },
    {
      "type": "B",
      "content": "four five six"
    }
  ]
}

POST test_index/test_type/3
{
  "contents": [
    {
      "type": "A",
      "content": "one two three four"
    },
    {
      "type": "B",
      "content": "five six"
    }
  ]
}

POST test_index/test_type/4
{
  "contents": [
    {
      "type": "A",
      "content": "one two three"
    },
    {
      "type": "B",
      "content": "five six"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now let's query for the string "four" in the `content` field according to the conditions you specified:

```
POST test_index/test_type/_search
{
   "query": {
      "nested": {
         "path": "contents",
         "query": {
            "bool": {
               "should": [
                  {
                     "bool": {
                        "must": [
                           {
                              "match": {
                                 "contents.type": "A"
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "match": {
                                 "contents.content": "four"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "match": {
                        "contents.content": "four"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The results:

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 1.6228913,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "test_type",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1.6228913,
            "_source": {
               "contents": [
                  {
                     "type": "A",
                     "content": "one two three four"
                  },
                  {
                     "type": "B",
                     "content": "five six"
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "test_type",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1.0997313,
            "_source": {
               "contents": [
                  {
                     "type": "A",
                     "content": "one two three four"
                  },
                  {
                     "type": "B",
                     "content": "four five six"
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "test_type",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.20286141,
            "_source": {
               "contents": [
                  {
                     "type": "A",
                     "content": "one two three"
                  },
                  {
                     "type": "B",
                     "content": "four five six"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here you can see docs with type "A" and string "four" in the content are ranked higher than doc with content "four" in type "B".

Comment: It seems like this works. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: The problem I have is that I am using multi_match-query for the contents where match-queries are enough.